# Can't fix Active Record Pending Migration Error

Tags: json, rest, activerecord, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

**i am trying to make a demo restful json api**

using this link:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one

but when i trying to run following command

```
$ bundle exec rspec

ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

error generated

i tried many solution available in stack overflow but no effect happen so far



C:\ruby\imran-api>bundle exec rspec
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:573:in `check_pending!':  (ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError)

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:586:in `load_schema_if_pending!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block in maintain_test_schema!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `suppress_messages'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `maintain_test_schema!'
        from C:/ruby/imran-api/spec/rails_helper.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/ruby/imran-api/spec/controllers/items_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/ruby/imran-api/spec/controllers/items_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `load_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/rspec:22:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/rspec:22:in `<main>'
```

[full error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmtwc.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run migration files for test environment first:

```
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

Answer (score 0):

for window

first go to bin folder:

```
cd bin
```

then run the below code:

```
rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```